# Javascript form resubmission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a simple HTML/Javascript form which upon submission checks the username and pass with Parse(.com) and shows the right page according to the specific user.

When first submitting the form everything runs great. But when submitting and then returning to the form page (using the browser back button) the submission event is not fired anymore (not even the console.log()). not by pressing the submit button and not by pressing Enter.

Here are some code snippets:

**Head:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_login").submit(function(e) {
      console.log("In form submit login")
      init();
      var name = $("#inp_user").val();
      var pass = $("#inp_pass").val();
      console.log("Name: " + name + " User: " + pass)
      login(name, pass);
    })
 })
```

**Body:**

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page_login" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login Screen</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="div-widget">
            <h3>Login details</h3>
            <form id="form_login">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="inp_user">User name:</label> <input type="email"
                        id="inp_user">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="inp_pass">Password</label> <input type="password"
                        id="inp_pass">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="btn_login" value="Login"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="div-widget">
            <span id="out_res"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
//More div data-role="page" here....
</body>
```

Comment: How are you setting the ACTION on the form?

Comment: I don't see an `e.preventDefault()` call anywhere?

Comment: @Diodeus I'm sorry but I don't really know what do I need for in this specific case. (I'm not very familiar with JavaScript or HTML).

Comment: @Bergi This might be true, but with or without it it's the same outcome

Comment: The "ACTION" is the URL the form is sending the info to - if this is missing the form will not work. There is not one defined, so it must be set using JS somewhere, which is not shown in your code.

Comment: I did a small example on [**jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/n48sb/) that makes use of `e.preventDefault` as @Bergi pointed out. worked fine for me - hope it is of use?!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz: Thank you for this try, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Diodeus but in this case where all the login data is sent using the login function while reading directly from the input fields, what do I need the ACTION for?

Comment: jsfiddle did work! - what error do you get?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz I updated the [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/n48sb/6/) and it now shows the same problem. Do login once and than back to login screen. The login function will not be called again

Answer (score 0):

According to given information I did a new example on [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n48sb/8/). So you forgot mention that you are using `jquery-mobile`. Furthermore using a `<form>` does cause behaviour described!

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page_login" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Login Screen</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="div-widget">
                <h3>Login details</h3>
                <!-- removed form - as you do not really need it-->
                <!-- you may keep it, but you MAY NOT submit the form! -->
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="inp_user">User name:</label>
                    <input type="email"
                        id="inp_user">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="inp_pass">Password</label>
                    <input type="password"
                        id="inp_pass">
                </div>
                <!-- <input type="submit" id="btn_login" value="Login"></input>-->
                <!-- instead, make use of button -->
                <a id="btn_login" href="#page_2" data-role="button">Login</a>
            </div>
            <div class="div-widget">
                <span id="out_res"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page_2" data-theme="a">Page 2</div>
    <!-- More div data-role="page" here....  -->
</body>
```

Instead of submitting a form - which causes the problem when hitting "back" within the browser, I decided to use a href - `data-role="button"`. Bound a *click handler* and `prevent-Default` if login fails (commented out right now)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_login").click(function(e) {
      console.log("clicked href")

      //init(); // commented out as not provided within your question
      var name = $("#inp_user").val();
      var pass = $("#inp_pass").val();
      console.log("Name: " + name + " User: " + pass)
      //login(name, pass); // commented out as not provided within your question

      /*if (LOGIN_FAILED)
      {
          console.log("login failed");
          e.preventDefault(); 
      }*/
    })
 })
```

Comment: Forms have semantic value. Keep the form tag and just do `e.preventDefault()` on the `submit` event of the form to

Comment: I did try an example with a form tag and e.preventDefault() - see comments on question - it did not work! as I mentioned we may keep form tag - but apparently submit did prevent this example from working! @Bojangles